# Hide Preview Icon in dock after `cmd+w`

Tags: macos, dock, preview, shortcut

I usually close stuff with `cmd+w` but if I do that with Preview it keep the program open in the Dock even if the file was closed.

I know that using `cmd+q` will do the trick but I'd like to have the same behaviour with `cmd+w`.

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/133158/preview-is-closed-in-mavericks-when-last-window-is-closed?rq=1

Comment: @Tetsujin `defaults write com.apple.Preview NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool FALSE && killall -HUP Finder` didn't help. Other suggestions?